# Pytorch required_grad=False does not freeze network parameters when running on GPU

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to freeze a layer of a toy model when training using Pytorch. In the following code, when I run the code on CPU, the layer isn't updated. (Please see the code line `print("%.8f" % np.max(np.abs(before -after)))`). However, when I run the code on GPU, the layer is updated. What is wrong with my implementation?

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

def toNP(x):
    return x.detach().to('cpu').numpy()

# toy feed-forward net
class Sub_Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Sub_Net, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 3)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.Sub_Net = Sub_Net()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10, 3)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(3, 3)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):

        y = self.Sub_Net(x)

        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = self.fc4(x)
        x = self.fc5(x)
        return x+y

def generator_step(net, optimizer, criterion, input, target):

    output = net(input)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    net.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

def discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, input, target):

    for param in net.Sub_Net.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False

    before = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)

    output = net(input)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    net.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    after = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)

    print("%.8f" % np.max(np.abs(before -after)) )


# Run model on GPU
# net = Net().type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
# random_input = Variable(torch.randn(10, )).cuda()
# random_target = Variable(torch.randn(1, )).cuda()

# Run model on CPU
net = Net()
random_input = Variable(torch.randn(10, ))
random_target = Variable(torch.randn(1, ))

# loss
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, net.parameters()), lr=0.1)

for epoch in range(1, 10):

    generator_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target)
    discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target)
```

Results when running on CPU

```
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
```

Results when running on GPU

```
0.06700575
0.04242781
0.03090768
0.02379489
0.01885229
0.01519108
0.01237211
0.01014686
0.00836059
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems it's not CPU / GPU acting differently, but it is about .to('cpu') function in your toNP function.

If given tensor is on GPU, it returns copied tensor on cpu, while it returns given original object when the given tensor is already on CPU.
Please refer more on this [site](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.cpu.html).

To clarify, I've added print function to your *discriminator_step* as follows:

```
def discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, input, target):

    for param in net.Sub_Net.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False

    before = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)
    print(f'Before:\n{before}')

    output = net(input)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    net.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print(f'Before:\n{before}')
    after = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)
    print(f'After:\n{after}')

    print("dff: %.8f" % np.max(np.abs(before -after)) )
```

Then the code yields results when on CPU (for 1 epoch):

```
Before:
[[-0.0222426   0.06449176  0.41833472]
 [-0.3276776  -0.22486973  0.38021228]
 [-0.37726757  0.26268137 -0.05000275]]
Before:
[[ 0.04476321  0.13149747  0.48534054]
 [-0.2606718  -0.15786391  0.44721812]
 [-0.31026173  0.32968715  0.01700307]]
After:
[[ 0.04476321  0.13149747  0.48534054]
 [-0.2606718  -0.15786391  0.44721812]
 [-0.31026173  0.32968715  0.01700307]]
dff: 0.00000000
```

and on GPU:

```
Before:
[[-0.06808002  0.39740798  0.55723506]
 [-0.17421165 -0.36702433 -0.4208245 ]
 [-0.37865937 -0.52346057 -0.15856335]]
Before:
[[-0.06808002  0.39740798  0.55723506]
 [-0.17421165 -0.36702433 -0.4208245 ]
 [-0.37865937 -0.52346057 -0.15856335]]
After:
[[-0.13508584  0.4644138   0.6242409 ]
 [-0.24121748 -0.30001852 -0.35381868]
 [-0.31165355 -0.5904664  -0.22556916]]
dff: 0.06700583
```

It shows **before** values are changed since the returned **before** tensor shares the same storage with **net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight** when on CPU.
Layers are updated regardless of CPU and GPU since they are already in parameter groups of the Adam optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for your response first!! What you mean is that either on CPU or on GPU can cause the same problem because "they are already in parameter groups of the Adam optimizer"?

Comment: Yes. Since the parameters of Sub_Net are already in optimizer with requires_grad=True, they are updated anyway even if you set requires_grad=False in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

(See edit for the actual answer to the question, the top question is still relevant to those experiencing this problem in a broader sense)

Seems directly related to [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/freezing-layers-issue-for-parallel-gpu/73658/3).

If you take the param grad removal out of the forward call, it works:

```
def discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, input, target):     
    before = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)      
    output = net(input) 
    loss = criterion(output, target) 
    net.zero_grad() 
    loss.backward() 
    optimizer.step() 
 
    after = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)      
    print("%.8f" % np.max(np.abs(before -after)) ) 
 
# Run model on GPU 
net = Net().type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor) 
random_input = Variable(torch.randn(10, )).cuda() 
random_target = Variable(torch.randn(1, )).cuda() 
for param in net.Sub_Net.parameters():  
    param.requires_grad = False  
# Run model on CPU 
#net = Net() 
#random_input = Variable(torch.randn(10, )) 
#random_target = Variable(torch.randn(1, )) 
...
 
for epoch in range(1, 10): 
 
    generator_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target) 
    discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target)
```

Which gives the output:

```
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
0.00000000
```

**EDIT**

You can just set the grad to `None` during the forward pass, which makes the Adam optimizer ignore it. If you just use zero grad Adam has moving averages which still change the values (I also checked this as SGD works with just `net.Sub_Net.zero_grad()`).

```
def generator_step(net, optimizer, criterion, input, target):
    beforeG = toNP(net.fc2.weight)
    beforeD = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)
    output = net(input)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    net.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    afterG = toNP(net.fc2.weight)
    afterD = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)
    print("gen step - G %.8f" % np.max(np.abs(beforeG -afterG)) )
    print("gen step - D %.8f" % np.max(np.abs(beforeD -afterD)) )

def discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, input, target):
    beforeG = toNP(net.fc2.weight)
    beforeD = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)
    output = net(input)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    net.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    for param in net.Sub_Net.parameters():
        param.grad = None
    #print(net.fc3.weight.grad)
    #print(net.Sub_Net.fc3.weight.grad)
    optimizer.step()
    afterG = toNP(net.fc2.weight)
    afterD = toNP(net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight)
    print("disc step - G %.8f" % np.max(np.abs(beforeG -afterG)) )
    print("disc step - D %.8f" % np.max(np.abs(beforeD -afterD)) )

# Run model on GPU
net = Net().type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
random_input = Variable(torch.randn(10, )).cuda()
random_target = Variable(torch.randn(1, )).cuda()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD([i for i in net.parameters()], lr=0.1)
for epoch in range(1, 3):
    generator_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target)
    discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target)

optimizer = optim.Adam([i for i in net.parameters()], lr=0.1)
for epoch in range(1, 3):
    generator_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target)
    discrimination_step(net, optimizer, criterion, random_input, random_target)
```

Outputs:

```
gen step - G 0.02727062
gen step - D 0.03749144
disc step - G 0.00164142
disc step - D 0.00000000
gen step - G 0.00133285
gen step - D 0.00459737
disc step - G 0.00046796
disc step - D 0.00000000

gen step - G 0.09999971
gen step - D 0.09999990
disc step - G 0.08018596
disc step - D 0.00000000
gen step - G 0.08054254
gen step - D 0.07518816
disc step - G 0.06967809
disc step - D 0.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your implementation does not match my intention. What I want is 
1) update net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight during the generation_step
2) do not update net.Sub_Net.fc2.weight during the discrimination_step

Comment: Apologies, see my edit

Comment: Still, this does not seem to explain why the behavior is different on CPU vs. GPU.

Comment: @Ivan [This line](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/9d925c1d6f81ad85bdc1b1aaa68efe6972c6f0ac/torch/optim/adam.py#L62) seems to suggest that when you set `.requires_grad` to False after already computing a gradient, this check will pass because it has an associated gradient and `.requires_grad` is never checked. SGD does not have this problem and I'm not sure what this has to do with the GPU.

Comment: Nevermind, SGD works because it doesn't have tracked moving averages, which are applied even when the gradient is 0.

Comment: I think the question is about why there exist a different behavior for CPU and GPU

Comment: See @Taeyoung Son's answer below for the reason why

Comment: @jhso Thank you for your practical solution!! It helps me indeed!! As you said, Taeyoung Son's answer seems to explain "why"!!